# Chasing down this lemma on infinite abelian locally finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I'm translating a paper from the 70's where the author cites László Fuchs' *Abelian groups* (the entire book, no page number). As you can imagine, given the size and differences in editions of Fuchs' book, I am having trouble connecting the dots.

Here is the situation: $G$ is an infinite, abelian, and locally finite group. $H$ is an infinite subgroup of $G$ which is of finite index in $G$. From this, the step in a proof I am reading continues this way

> ... we deduce the socle of $G$ is of finite length and that $G$ is an Artinian group.

The justification of the block above is what I am asking about.

In the newest edition (2015) of Fuchs' *Abelian groups*, I feel think the relevant theorem is this:

> Theorem 5.3 (Prufer, Kurosh, Yahya)
>
> T.F.A.E:
>
> (i) $A$ is finitely cogenerated
>
> (ii) $A$ is an essential extension of a finite group
>
> (iii) $A$ is torsion of finite rank
>
> (iv) $A$ is a direct sum of a finite number of cocyclic groups
>
> (v) the subgroups of $A$ satisfy the minimum condition
>
> [later] Obeserve that (ii) is equivalent to the finiteness of the socle in a torsion group.

This is the very first theorem in the section, preceded only by the definition of finite cogeneration.

The local finiteness obviously makes $G$ torsion, so I can see why both conclusions are linked... but how do you use the fact that $|G:H|$ is finite to prove one of these conditions?

I feel like I'm overlooking some connection between $G/H$ and $G$, possibly about the socles. In general module theory, there usually isn't a connection between the two, but perhaps since $G$ is locally finite there is a connection in my blind spot.

---

I've decided the original source is in order:

[image]

$A$ is a right self-injective ring, and $G$ is, as proven in an earlier step, at least a locally finite group. The $G_1$ and $H_1$ in this snippet are the $G$ and $H$ I was referring to in my original description. The citation (7) refers to Fuchs' *Abelian groups*. The theorem of Faith has to do with the injectivity of a free $A[H_1]$ module. Basically it allows you to conclude that $A[G_1]$ is a direct sum of finitely many copies of $A[H_1]$, and this means $|G_1:H_1|$ is finite.

Perhaps the theorem that's needed (which did not come out in my description above) is that if $G$ is a locally finite, infinite abelian group whose infinite subgroups are all of finite index, $G$ is Artinian? If this is the case, then a reference to that result would be an acceptable solution to this problem. (Hopefully in Fuchs, but elsewhere would be fine.)

Comment: Without any other assumptions on $H$ you can always take $G=H,$ so $H$ is irrelevant. An infinite product of $C_2$’s is a counterexample (non Artinian) unless I’m missing something.

Comment: @Dap You're right... I thought i presented the problem faithfully but I will try to double-check.

Comment: @Dap I've added some of the original source material. Perhaps there are stronger properties available that I overlooked. This is the only step of the proof that I don't get, and I'd like to figure out for sure if there is a gap here or not.

Comment: @Dap I think I might have seen what I accidentally occluded in my original description. If you have a locally finite, infinite abelian group, and all infinite subgroups have finite index, does that imply the five conditions in the theorem?

Comment: @rschwieb: Let P be the property that all infinite subgroups have finite index. If G has Property P, then so does any infinite subgroup of G. But no infinite, locally finite, semisimple group has P. Thus if G has property P, its socle must be finite. Hence (ii) holds for G, since G is an essential extension of its socle.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Ah!  Of course, you should submit it as a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem about the class $\mathcal A$ of infinite, abelian, locally finite groups.

Let $P$ be the property that all infinite subgroups have finite index. If $G\in\mathcal A$ has Property $P$, then so does any infinite subgroup of $G$. But no infinite, locally finite, semisimple group has $P$, so if $G\in\mathcal A$ has $P$, then the socle of $G$ must be finite. This shows that (ii) holds for $G$, since any $G\in\mathcal A$ is an essential extension of its socle.

Comment: Thanks... all the pieces suddenly fall into place! I should have stared at that item some more...